# Can I speed up AWK program using NR function

Tags: awk

I am using awk to pull out data form a file that us +30M records.  I know within a few 1000 records where the records I want are.  I am curious if I can cut down on the time it take awk to find the records by telling it a starting point setting the NR.  for example, my record is >25 million lines in I could use the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{NR=25000000}{rest of my script}' in
```

would this make awk skip straight to the 25M record and save me the time of it scanning each record before that?

For a better example, I am using this AWK in a loop in sh.  I need the normal output of the awk script, but I would also like it pass along the NR when it finished to the next interation when loop comes back to this script again.

```
awk -v n=$line -v r=$record 'BEGIN{a=1}$4==n{print $10;a=2}($4!=n&&a==2){(pass NR out to $record);exit}' in
```

Comment: How often do you pull values out of these files?  If you do it a lot, it might pay off to put the values into a database, or at least into some sort of file format that is easier to work with than simple text.

Comment: How long time does it really take to scan (that is, just skipping with `NR>=2000000`) 20 million records? Have you tested it?

Comment: What do you mean by `pass NR out to $record`?

Comment: to get all the way through the file can take 1-2 minutes, with 100 lines to scan, this can get tiresome, hence why I added the exit to the start so it didn't scan to the end.  I was just trying to find a way to make it not have to scan from the start as I know at least how far in a file has to be.

Comment: So to scan the file once takes 1-2 minutes? And you have to scan the file 100 times?

Comment: if it scans to the end of the file yes.  Since I have the exit command in my script, the program runs quickly at the start, then slows as it has to search further and further into the file.

Comment: I see, why do you check `$4`, that is: `$4==n`? Why not just `NR==n`?. Doing the latter would prevent awk from doing field splitting on each record, which might be quite expensive.. (Awk (at least gawk version 4) does lazy splitting of records, meaning that it does not split each record into fields unless you explicitly reference `$i` where `i>0` or `NF`)

Comment: after timing there doesn't' appear to be a penalty for splitting the fields or not. (doesn't matter since $4 is not == NR for my search)

Comment: Interesting.. Which version of awk are you running?

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.5 is the verision I am using

Comment: Yes that is an old version :) You could try to upgrade to gawk version 4.1.. But that would not matter for this case, anyway since you have to check fields explicitly for each iteration..

Comment: Maybe you could do all the processing in a single awk run? Instead of calling awk 100 times, just call it once and do the processing in the shell script from within awk..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Let's try it:

```
$ cat -n file
     1  one
     2  two
     3  three
     4  four
$ awk 'BEGIN {NR=2} {print NR, $0}' file
3 one
4 two
5 three
6 four
```

Are your records fixed length, or do you know the average line length? If yes, then you can use a language that allows you to open a file and seek to a position. Otherwise you have to read all those lines:

```
awk -v start=25000000 'NR < start {next} {your program here}' file
```

---

To maintain your position between runs of the script, I'd use a language like perl: at the end of the run use `tell()` to output the current position, say to a file; then at the start of the next run, use `seek()` to pick up where you left off. Add a check that the starting position is less than the current file size, in case the file was truncated.

Comment: In Gnu Awk version 4.1, you can write extensions to awk i c-language. Maybe these things could let you skip directly to a given byte position in the file?

Comment: @glenn_jackman can I use the tell() seek() in a pipe with awk?  I find perl a little confusing, so I don't know how I would implement this.  Can you give an example?

Comment: What language are you comfortable with?

Comment: @glennjackman I am more familiar with python than I am with perl.  Can you do it in python?

Comment: Nope. I'd recommend taking a stab at it then posting another question if you run into trouble, showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Records generally have no fixed size so there is no way for `awk` but to scan the first part of the file even just to skip them.

Should you want to skip the first part of the input file and you (roughly) know the size to ignore, you can use `dd` to truncate the input, eg here assuming a record is 80 bytes wide:

```
dd if=inputfile bs=25MB skip=80 | awk ...
```

Finally, you can avoid `awk` to scan the last records by exiting from the awk script when you have hit the end of the interesting zone.

Answer (score 0):

One way (Using sed), if you know the line numbers

```
for n in 3 5 8 9  .... 
do
  sed -n "${n}p" file |awk command
done
```

or

```
sed -n "25000,30000p" file |awk command
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this with an editor that reads a file line by line becuase no matter what you do it has to read those lines.  Even if I delete all the lines up to the desired point with sed or awk after it reads the file, it still has to read all the lines following to print out the rest of the file, so I end up losing time due to reading through the file twice.